# MariaDB , Python Insert JSON Format - Syntax

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I just run a MariaDB , mysql DB and waste my time with some JSON Format fun.

My Table is like :

```
MariaDB [xx]> desc xx;
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| xx               | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| HERE             | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xxxxxx           | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xxxxxx           | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xxxx             | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attr             | longtext      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

JSON FORMAT :

```
{
     "id":1 ,
     "xx": "string",
     "HERE": {"1":"string","2":"string"},
     ... rest ...
}
```

My error is about HERE.
Whats the right INSERT query for this Format ?
Thanks Guys.

Comment: I would venture you need to pass the entire json as a string, not as a json object of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mariadb 10.6 or higher, then you can use `JSON_TABLE` to convert json into rows :

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, xx, HERE)
SELECT *
     FROM
       JSON_TABLE(
         '{
            "id":1 ,
            "xx": "string",
            "HERE": {"1":"string","2":"string"}
         }',
         "$"
         COLUMNS(
           id INT PATH "$.id",
           xx longtext PATH "$.xx",
           HERE json PATH "$.HERE"
         )
       ) data;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0wnMyGni)

Comment: Is there any easy way to INSERT it on a table with MariaDB 10.5 sinces iam not able to upgrade.

Comment: It would be possible but with complete different method, It would be good idea if you can create a new question mentioning That you are using MariaDB 10.5, I'm sure you will get an answer